# Copy an updated column to another column automatically by CREATE TRIGGER

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server.

There's a table with some columns: `column1, column2, ...`

The user has access to `column1`, and he can update it's content.

Now I want to create a trigger to copy the new content of `column1` to `column2` automatically.

e.g.

```
set column2 = column1 AFTER UPDATE of (column1)
```

I've created a trigger on the table using this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[mytrigger]
ON [dbo].[mytable]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
   IF UPDATE(userName)
   BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      -- HERE I SHOULD WRITE A CODE TO COPY NEW DATA OF COLUMN1 TO COLUMN2 !! :-??

   END
```

WHAT code should I use instead of the comment ??

I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use query below. It uses `INSERTED` table to avoid replacing all rows

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mytable.column2 = i.column1
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN INSERTED i
ON i.idcolumn=mytable.idcolumn
```